# A simple calculator (only add) oop javascript

Tags: javascript

guys, I have problems with a basic calculator js object only to add numbers input1 + input2 = input3. I have no clue how to display the result for input 1 and 2 in input 3 ( result ). From now I just get value from inputs using show('1'). This is my code

JS

```
function calculator(){
    this.result = document.getElementById('3');
    this.show = function(id){
        var a =document.getElementById(id).value
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<label for="1">
<input type="text" id = '1'>
</label>
<br><br>
<label for="2">
<input type="text" id = '2'>
</label>
<br><br>  
<label for="3">
<input type="text" id = 3>
</label>
<button onclick="click()">+</button>
  <script src="jss.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is your click() function?

Comment: ´id`s shouldn't be numbers. The should start with a letter or an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function calculator() {
  var item1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('item1').value);
  var item2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('item2').value);
  document.getElementById('item3').value = item1 + item2;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="item1" value="0" oninput="calculator()">
<br><br>
<input type="number" id="item2" value="0" oninput="calculator()">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="item3" disabled>
<button onclick="calculator()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code. There is no `click()` defined in your code, it should be `calculator()`. You have to covert the value before the calculation. Otherwise string concatenation will happen as the default type of input value is string. You can use `parseFloat()` to do that.

Try the following way:

```js
function calculator(){
    document.getElementById('3').value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('1').value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById('2').value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="1">
<input type="text" id = '1'>
</label>
<br><br>
<label for="2">
<input type="text" id = '2'>
</label>
<br><br>  
<label for="3">
<input type="text" id = '3'>
</label>
<button onclick="calculator()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Call your function calculator() rather than click(), which actually isn't a function you've set up.

```
<button onclick="calculator()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it like this**

You need to grab both the input fields. Extract value from them change them to number and than after addition add it to third input.

```js
function calculator(){
    let result = document.getElementById('3');
    let input1 = document.getElementById('1').value;
    let input2 = document.getElementById('2').value;
    let final = Number(input1) + Number(input2);
    result.value = final;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<label for="1">
<input type="text" id = '1'>
</label>
<br><br>
<label for="2">
<input type="text" id = '2'>
</label>
<br><br>  
<label for="3">
<input type="text" id = 3>
</label>
<button onclick="calculator()">+</button>

</body>

</html>
```